# Is there another way I can check the .net role a user is in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have many checks to determine what role a user is in 
and then assign a role number. Is there some way that
I could simplify the checks?

```
        if (User.IsInRole("Super"))
        {
            ViewBag.Role = 30;
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            ViewBag.Role = 20;
        }
        ...
        ...
        else if (User.IsInRole("Guest"))
        {
            ViewBag.Role = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Role = 5;
        }
```

What I need to do is find the highest role the user is in and then assign that value to ViewBag.Role which is a dynamic variable. The code above does work but all the if and else statements don't look like good coding practice to me.

Comment: Can you show the User.IsInRole() code?  That would be helpful

Comment: How about a switch statement?

Comment: +1 for recognizing the multiple if/switch statement code-smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a property to your User class:

```
    public virtual int RoleNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.IsInRole("Super")) return 30;
            if (this.IsInRole("Admin")) return 20;
            if (this.IsInRole("Guest")) return 10;
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

And then in the View:

```
ViewBag.Role = User.RoleNumber
```

Comment: probably an extension method, because I think is about the User class from the framework

Answer (score 2):

If a user has only one role, you could use the GetRoles method, which returns an array of roles, to check if it has anyt values.

If it does - you could parse the first and the only role the user has as an enum with the values you want to provide the view bag. If the array has novalues - you can provide the default minimal value.

In case there is more than one role, it can be solved in a more "sophisticated way", but a tthe end of the day it will probably cost more to develop, understand and execute than the simple if..else code

Answer (score 2):

I would use enums instead of strings. This allows you to have compile time checking on the names.

The following code gives you the flexiblty to change (ad or remove) roles without having the change the underlining role checking logic.

```
    public int IsInRole()
    {
        int defaultValue = (int)UserRole.Default;
        var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (UserRole));

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            if(User.IsInRole(name))
            {
                defaultValue = (int)((UserRole)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), name));
                break;
            }
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }

public enum UserRole
{
    Super = 30,
    Admin = 20,
    Guest = 10,
    Default = 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try someting like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> weight = new Dictionary<string, int>();
weight.Add("Super", 30);
weight.Add("Admin", 20);
weight.Add("Guest", 10);

string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
if (roles.Any())
{
  ViewBag.Role = weight.Where(w => roles.Contains(w.Key))
    .OrderBy(w => w.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
else
{
  ViewBag.Role = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your Role class as

```
public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

You can use

```
var roles = GetYourRoles(); // IEnumerable<Role>    
var result = roles.First(r => User.IsInRole(r.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about extending ASP.NET's Role table? If each role has a fixed weight, then create a table (called `RoleWeight` or something) and set your desired weight with that role. That way, you don't have to set anything (and eliminate code that "don't look like good coding practice"), but rather have the value already there.